# Downloading files to remote server HTTP 400 error

Tags: c#, http, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-400

Program uses `DownloadString` function of `Web.Client`.

The url's I have tried so far:

```
http://xxx.xxx.x.xx/blabla.ashx?command=blabla - Http 404

http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:port/blabla.ashx?command=blabla - Http 400
```

When I type

```
http://xxx.xxx.x.xx
```

IIS page shows up as expected.

Comment: 400 Error is a Bad Request. 404 means that you communicated with the server and the server said that there wasn't a file at the given URI. Are you sure that is the correct server and address?

Comment: When I try those url's in localhost like `http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:port/blabla.ashx?command=blabla` there is no problem. I assume that the url is correct by doing this test.

Comment: I can't be sure then. Fortunately, you know you are reaching the server but not finding the file. It could be something with virtual directories (VDIR), where the external connection's root is mapped to another location, but this is me just spit-balling now. If you have other files on the server that are accessible I would double check their formats.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved now. It seems you have to add a binding to IIS to use an address in remote machine.